# sympy integration limits error: TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'

Tags: python, sympy

The following code

```
from sympy import *
r = Symbol('r', real=True, positive=True)
a = Symbol('a', real=True, positive=True)
Integral(1/r**2,(r,oo,a)).doit()
```

results in an error

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'
```

whereas

```
-Integral(1/r**2,(r,a,oo)).doit()
```

, which is an equivalent formulation of the integral above, gives the correct result: `-1/a`.

Furthermore, lowering the restrictions for the domain of `a`

```
r = Symbol('r', real=True, positive=True)
a = Symbol('a')
Integral(1/r**2,(r,oo,a)).doit()
```

gives the correct result as well.

Is this a bug in `sympy` or what is going wrong here?

**Edit:** It is completely valid to integrate from Infinity to a positive value. Mathematica does the job right as I wrote in my comment addressed to @BenT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that this is a bug in `sympy`.
I opened an issue in their github (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13536) which will be resolved soon.